# Load entire page into var, manipulate with jQuery and rewrite to page?

Tags: jquery

Is this possible? Trying with the code below but missing something missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7t7wag/1/

```
$("h1").click(function(){
  var htmlvar = $('html')[0].outerHTML;
  $(htmlvar).find("h1").html("NEWTITLE");
  $("html").html($("html", htmlvar).html());
 });
```

Comment: Why?  Why not just change the h1 html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Normally, of course, you would simply modify the `h1` contents directly in the DOM. I'll assume you have a good reason to want to do this in a fragment separate from the page itself, or you wouldn't have bothered asking the question.)

```js
// Get your html string from wherever:
var htmlstr = $('#foo').html(); // or just a string

// convert the string into a jQuery object:
var fragment = $(htmlstr);

// Manipulate its contents as needed:
fragment.find("h1").html("NEWTITLE");

// Now put the changed HTML string wherever:
$('#foo').html(fragment.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo"><div>Here are some <h1>HTML tags</h1></div></div>
```

I don't believe it's possible to replace the entire HTML page as you're trying to do in your snippet -- that would overwrite *everything*, including the script that's trying to do the overwriting.  At most, overwrite the `body` contents (though even that is overkill, as it will destroy any event bindings or the like that have previously been attached to the DOM -- try to limit the changes to as small a part of the DOM tree as you can.)

Comment: Good comment. Yes it is for another reason than just the h1 tag. Want to get the current page html and manipulate some parts and then save to a file. It actually works when I get an external html file with Ajax, but seems more difficult to get the entire page html.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just change the text of the `<h1/>` and avoid altering the entirety of the html all together? It seems pretty redundant to me.

```js
$(function() {

  $("h1").click(function() {
    $(this).text('NEWTITLE');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>
  TEST
</h1>
```